# simple string decoding using java

Tags: java

Consider the following encoding scheme A-> 1, B -> 2, Z- > 26. Given an encoding (string containing at most 1000 digits) using this scheme, find the number of possible decodings. The output should return a string containing the number of decodings. 
Note: Just Fill out the function coding

Input Format

A single line String

Output Format

A single line String

Sample Input

121

Sample Output

3

Explanation

Possible decodings for input "121" are ABA,AU,LA.

Sample Input #2:
1201 
Sample Output #2:
3 
Possible decodings for input "1201" are ATA,AT,TA

Comment: Homework..!! without giving a try

Comment: plz explain the logic with source code in java

Comment: whats the logic behind that problem,its confusing

Comment: Post what you have tried so far. We will help you with any problem you are facing while implementing the problem but we would not solve your problem.

Comment: public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner t=new Scanner(System.in);
      String sampleString;
       int y=0;
       sampleString=t.nextLine();
      String[] stringArray = sampleString.split("");
      int[] intArray = new int[stringArray.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
         
         intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
      }
      for (int i=0;i<stringArray.length;i++) {
          if(intArray[i]!=0)
              {
              y++;
          }
      }
         System.out.println(y);
      
   }
} @ankur

Comment: @cv7 add the codes via an edit to your question.

Comment: u wanna help me,come with source code plzzz

Comment: the code you have posted in the comment please edit your question and post the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

static {
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; ++i)
        map.put(Integer.toString(i), Character.toString((char)('A' + i - 1)));
}

static void decode(String decoded, String encoded, List<String> result) {
    int len = encoded.length();
    if (len == 0)
        result.add(decoded);
    else
        for (int i = 1, max = Math.min(2, len); i <= max; ++i) {
            String e = map.get(encoded.substring(0, i));
            if (e != null)
                decode(decoded + e, encoded.substring(i), result);
        }
}

public static List<String> decode(String encoded) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    decode("", encoded, result);
    return result;
}

@Test
public void testDecode() {
    System.out.println(decode("121"));
    System.out.println(decode("1201"));
}
```

The results are:

```
[ABA, AU, LA]
[ATA]
```